# Unconfirmed Bitcoin transaction over 48hr

Tags: blockchain

Please I need miners here to help me confirm the Bitcoin transaction with the hash ID below. Thanks

e1f583b820df77e71f3e280397c2ae4348f72d9c263e92733445926e468df2d5

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not even a question, just asking for miners to mine a certain transaction.